# Failed assertion: line 38 pos 12: 'displayName != null': is not true

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Firebase Flutter login getting error

> 04-28 14:31:21.261 7687-8012/com.companyname.firebaselogin I/flutter: 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart': Failed assertion: line 38: 'displayName != null': is not true.

using same as the documented code -

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
print("signed in " + user.displayName);
return user;
}
```

> firebase_auth: "^0.5.5"
>
> google_sign_in: "^3.0.2"

Comment: I don't understand where the failure is coming from. What is line 38 in your code? If you have a full stack trace, can you add that to the question?

Comment: When I try to integrate the google signin with flutter it's giving this error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the log as you can see it's getting error on google_sign_in.dart package.

Comment: Got some hint it's happening only with few google account.

Comment: Most likely those accounts that give the problem don't have a display name. What I don't see though is where the problem is coming from. The error message says it comes from line 38, but I have no idea what line 38 is in the code you shared.

Comment: It's flutter offical library check for google_sign_in.dart